# Adding a datamodule to the delphi object repository

Tags: delphi

I am using D10 Pro. I added a datamodule to the object repository by right clicking it and selecting "Add to Repository" on the popup menu.

The datamodule shows up in the New>Other dialog and I am able to click the icon for it.  When I do, I get the following exception: "Unable to find both a form () and source file ().  The same exception occurs with forms I place there.  The object that came with Delphi load without any problem.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the.Xml file mentioned here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_the_Object_Repository?  There may be something obviously wrong about you DM's entry in it.  Fwiw, the couple of times I've had this error with earlier Delphi versions, iirc, removing the file from the repository and re-adding it fixed the problem.

Comment: I followed the directions you reference in your link.  Following your advice, I examined the file and cannot find anything obviously wrong with it for that entry.  I also have tried removing and reinstalling the form, but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

When adding items to the repository, you should avoid using dotnet style names for your files. For example, I originally named the file "MyLib.Datamodule.TextImporter.pas" and I received the error in my question.  I experienced the same problem with a form using the same dotnet style naming.  After changing the file name to "TextImporterDatamodule.pas" and adding it to the repository, I was able to use it to create new datamodules without a problem.  This is something Embarcadero needs to address.

Comment: I confirm this for forms, data modules and frames. And it still is a problem in Delphi 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: Same problem in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your q, but maybe this will help you track down your problem.

Contrary to what the DocWiki says for Seattle, the repository .Xml file is actually named "Repository.Xml" and in my case is located here:

```
C:\Users\MA\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\17.0\Repository.Xml
```

I added a data module to it, resulting in the entry shown below being added.
Notice that for a datamodule, the path to it is stored in its `IDString`
attribute along with the filename, unlike a form, where the path+name is stored
in the the `Value` attribute of the `FormName` node.

With that entry in place, unlike you I can then include a copy of it in a project
by going to `File | New | Other` in the IDE.  However, if I then change the
on-disk name of the folder where the  item is located, and try to use it, I get the error
message you quoted.  Of course, that doesn't mean that's why you're getting
it, but I thought it might help to see the repository entry for something that's known to work.

```
<Item IDString="D:\Delphi\Code\SO\Devex\DM1" CreatorIDString="BorlandDelphiRepositoryCreator">
     <Name Value="AAADataModule"/>
      <Icon Value=""/>
      <Description Value="MA datamodule"/>
      <Author Value="MA"/>
      <Personality Value="Delphi.Personality"/>
      <Platforms Value=""/>
      <Frameworks Value=""/>
      <Identities Value="RADSTUDIO"/>
      <Categories>
        <Category Value="InternalRepositoryCategory.MyCategory" Parent="Borland.Delphi.NewFiles">MyCategory</Category>
        <Category Value="Borland.Delphi.NewFiles" Parent="Borland.Delphi.New">Delphi Files</Category>
        <Category Value="Borland.Delphi.New" Parent="Borland.Root">Delphi Projects</Category>
      </Categories>
      <Type Value="FormTemplate"/>
      <Ancestor Value=""/>
      <FormName Value=""/>
      <Designer Value="Any"/>
</Item>
```

If this doesn't help, best I can suggest is to post your q in the IDE section
of EMBA's newsgroups here:

```
https://forums.embarcadero.com/forum.jspa?forumID=62
```

I don't think that should provoke cross-posting complaints, seeing as your q has been up here for a while without getting a definitive answer.

Comment: MartynA,  Thanks for your help.  I found the answer to my problem which I have posted.